# Number in my textbox into another textbox with a formula

Tags: c#, string, textbox, int, double

I'm bad at explaining things but i hope that you will understand me.

What you need to know:
**txtBruto1.Text is my textbox** and there is always a **random number** in there.
So in the formula rszbediende i want that my number in **txtBruto1 "/ 100 * 13.07"**
And with the other formules its the same. 
Now i'm getting an error:

> *input string was not in a correct format*.

But i tryed to solve this with:

```
String example;
example = txtBruto1.Text;
```

When i do that then i'm getting another fault : "Cannot use / in a string or int.

here is my code now:

```
rszbediende = Convert.ToDouble(txtBruto1.Text) / 100 * 13.07;
rszarbeider = Convert.ToDouble(txtBruto1.Text) / 100 * 13.07;
bruto_arbeider = Convert.ToDouble(txtBruto1.Text) / 100 * 108;
txtBrutoarbeidertotaal1.Text = Convert.ToString(bruto_arbeider);
```

Sorry if you don't understand me or the code.
My main language is not English so it is hard to spell.
If you still don't know what my Q is then please feel free to comment below.

Comment: On which line you get this error? What is the relevant textbox value that you want to convert double and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using braces around the conversion, to make sure the conversion result is used:

```
rszbediende = (Convert.ToDouble(txtBruto1.Text)) / 100 * 13.07;
```

What I would normally do to debug this type of probles is make the problem small by splitting the code in two lines:

```
 Double tmp = (Convert.ToDouble(txtBruto1.Text))
 rszbediende = tmp / 100 * 13.07;
```

This may help you to find out if something is wrong with the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are trying to enter the formula in the **txtBruto1** textbox? like 
"11.112 / 100 * 13.07" in the textbox. If yes, then this might be the reason for the error - "input string was not in a correct format."

Otherwise the code that you have written here is working fine. It will not throw errors on the scenario provided by you.